# arreglo de javascript dividirlo según sus valores

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objeto

Tengo dos arreglos los cuales los comparo donde coincida guardo el elemento en un arreglo pero quiero hacer lo mismo con los siguientes pero guardandolos en un arreglo distinto no que se guarden todos en el arreglo unidad.

```
array1 = [
{valor1: "13", valor2: "ejemplo1", valor3: "8"},
{valor2: "53", valor2: "ejemplo2", valor3: "9"},
{valor3: "56", valor2: "ejemplo3", valor3: "10"},
{valor4: "60", valor2: "ejemplo4", valor3: "11"},
];

array2= [
{valor1: "13", valor2: "ejemplo1" },
{valor2: "53", valor2: "ejemplo2" },
];

  for(var i=0;i<array2.length;i++)  
  {
    for(var j=0;j<array1.length;j++) 
    {
        if(array1[j].valor1 == array2[i].valor1){
             
            var unidad = new Array();
            unidad.push({   //Aqui es donde tengo el problema 
                  "valor1":array1[i].valor1, 
                  "valor2":array1[i].valor2,
                  "valor3":array1[i].valor3,
             }); 
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Compártenos que has intentado por favor y además si puedes explicar con un ejemplo de salida como esperas los datos sería mejor

Comment: quieres tener un array con solo valores1, otro con valores2 y lo mismo con valores3?.

Comment: array2= [
{valor1: "13", valor2: "ejemplo1" },
{valor2: "53", valor2: "ejemplo2" },
];

  for(var i=0;i<array2.length;i++)  
  {
    for(var j=0;j<array1.length;j++) 
   {
    if(array1[j].UNITID == array2[i].unitid){
       
     var unidad = new Array();
       unidad.push({   
                  "valor1":array1[i].valor1, 
                  "valor2":array1[i].valor2,
                  "valor3":array1[i].valor3,
             }); 
    }
    }
  }

Comment: tengo dos arreglos cada uno con longitudes diferentes comparo uno con el otro y donde coincida deseo sacar el elemento a un arreglo, y asi con los siguientes pero en arreglos diferentes

Comment: No entiendo nada, edita la pregunta y se más claro.

Comment: Saludos. Le sugiero con los datos que ya puso; colocar como espera queden (es decir la salida esperada con esos mismos datos). Esto debido a que ningún valor se repite y ademas fijate por ejemplo el 2do elemento tiene 2 `valor2` y el 3er elemento tiene 2 `valor3`.

Comment: Es cierto lo que dice @RobertoLeOr si no hay consistencia entre los valores que tienes que procesar no podemos aportar una solución exacta

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo, se quiere hacer coincidir **la primera propiedad y valor de cada elemento del primer array (`a1[x][0]`)** con **la primera propiedad y valor de cada elemento del segundo array (`a2[x][0]`)**, es decir, `a1[x][0] == a2[x][0]`, y a partir de esa coincidencia, agregar el elemento coincidente del primer array a un tercer array `a3`.

Para obtener la primera propiedad y el primer valor de un objeto se hace así, cada elemento del array es un objeto:

```
var propiedad = Object.keys(x)[0]
var valor = x[propiedad]
```

Se recorren los dos arrays mediante `map`, uno dentro de otro, por cada elemento del primer array, se recorre el segundo array:

```
array1.map(x=>{
    // ...
    return array2.map(y=>{
        // ..
    }
}
```

Se asigna al tercer array los elementos coincidentes

```
var array3 = array1.map(x=>{
    var propiedad_a1 = Object.keys(x)[0]
    var valor_a1 = x[propiedad_a1]

    return array2.map(y=>{
      var propiedad_a2 = Object.keys(y)[0]
      var valor_a2 = y[propiedad_a2]
      // ...
```

Para comparar que sean iguales los valores del primer array con los del segundo, se envuelven las propiedades y los valores en un array nuevo, y luego mediante `JSON.stringify` se lo convierte a *String*, cadenas de texto que se pueden comparar.

```
JSON.stringify([propiedad_a1, valor_a1]) ==
JSON.stringify([propiedad_a2, valor_a2])
```

Esto equivale a lo siguiente, lo cual es evaluado como verdadero:

```
'["valor1","13"]' == '["valor1","13"]'
```

Queda algo como:

```
  [{tal objeto} , true /*verdad*/ ]
, [{otro objeto} , false /*falso*/ ]
```

Entonces hay que filtrar los que sean verdaderos, y mantener solo el objeto, quitando el elemento `true` o `false`:

```
.filter(x=>x[1]) // Filtra los verdaderos
.map(x=>x[0])[0] // Mantiene solo el primero
```

Quedando algo así, que son los elementos coincidentes:

```
[{tal objeto}]
```

Código:

```js
var array1 = [
    {valor1: "13", valor2: "ejemplo1", valor3: "8"},
    {valor2: "53", valor2: "ejemplo2", valor3: "9"},
    {valor3: "56", valor2: "ejemplo3", valor3: "10"},
    {valor4: "60", valor2: "ejemplo4", valor3: "11"},
]
var array2 = [
    {valor1: "13", valor2: "ejemplo1" },
    {valor2: "53", valor2: "ejemplo2" },
]

var array3 = array1.map(x=>{
    var propiedad_a1 = Object.keys(x)[0]
    var valor_a1 = x[propiedad_a1]

    return array2.map(y=>{
      var propiedad_a2 = Object.keys(y)[0]
      var valor_a2 = y[propiedad_a2]
      return [x,(
        JSON.stringify([propiedad_a1, valor_a1]) ==
        JSON.stringify([propiedad_a2, valor_a2])
      )]
    }).filter(x=>x[1]).map(x=>x[0])[0]
}).filter(x=>x)

console.log(array3)
```

Comment: var nuevo1 = [
{valor1: "13", valor2: "ejemplo1", valor3: "8"},

]
 

var nuevo2 = [
{valor1: "53", valor2: "ejemplo2", valor3: "9"},

 ]

var nuevo3 = [
{valor1: "56", valor2: "ejemplo3", valor3: "10"},

 ]

var nuevo4 = [
{valor1: "60", valor2: "ejemplo4", valor3: "11"},

 ]       // Es la salida que se espera, respuesta de la pregunta de arriba.

Comment: @EderEsparza ¿Por qué necesitas separar cada elemento en una variable nueva? Además, el elemento del 53 no tiene `valor1`, tiene `valor2` y `valor2`.